# How can I capitalise a word proceeding a specific word

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Lets say I want to capitalise the first word following the word jumped. Example below

Original text:

```
the cow jumped over the moon
```

Amended text

```
the cow jumped OVER the moon
```

I have tried awk and sed but cant seem to get it right.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try with awk?

Comment: what if "jumped" is the last word in a line, should the first word of the next line be upper case?

Answer (score 7):

Loop the words in a row, and if the word before the current word (`$(i-1)`) is *jumped*, overwrite the current word ( `$i`) with `toupper($i)`.

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ($(i-1)=="jumped") $i=toupper($i); }}1'
```

You could also change the record separator to space to avoid the loop:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=" "} l=="jumped"{$0=toupper($0)} {l=$0}1'
```

Answer (score 7):

With `sed`:

- Enable extended regular expressions with the option `-E`.
- Then capture the specific word in a group `()` with the space after it `\s` so your example specific word will look like this `(jumped\s)`.
- Then capture the word after it in a second group like this `(\w+)`.
- Then call the two groups `\1` and `\2` and capitalize all letters in group number 2 with `\U` like this `\1\U\2`
- Then put the whole thing in `'s/string1/string2/g'` where `s` means search for `string1` and when found, change it to `string2` and `g` means global search i.e. search and substitute on all lines.
- Then use it on text from a pipe like so:

  ```
  echo "the cow jumped over the moon" | sed -E 's/(jumped\s)(\w+)/\1\U\2/g'
  ```
- Or use it on text from a file like so:

  ```
  sed -E 's/(jumped\s)(\w+)/\1\U\2/g' file
  ```
- And the result from your example will look like this:

  ```
  the cow jumped OVER the moon
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you want to use the output, you could do something like this (an idea that you could modify for your needs):

```
a="the cow jumped over the moon"
```

```
echo $a | awk '{
for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++){
if($(i-1)~/jumped/){printf toupper($i)}
else{printf $i}
printf " "}
}'
```

This will output:
`the cow jumped OVER the moon`

This assumes that the word to be modified is on the same line as "jumped".